# PHP file_get_contents return is empty

Tags: php

I try to fetch the content of an url. If I check the URL in a browser it works fine and there is content in the browser, but if I call the URL with `file_get_contents`, then `content_length` is empty.

If I call a simple php file with regular text, I get the content returned.

Is it possible to tell `file_get_contents` to call the URL, wait 5 seconds and then return the content?

Or would `curl` be a better solution?

Comment: Please provide full code example including response.